# How do I maintain folders structure when zipping in Java?

Tags: java, android, zip

I want zip up a folder structured like so:

temp/folder1/file1

temp/folder2/file2

temp/file3

and maintain the directory structure exactly.
Currently,  when I zip it, I get a zip that doesnt maintain the directory structure. It looks like this
file1
file2
file3

what do I do to add the files in their respective folders like all the normal zipping applications do?

This is the code I have so far:

```
package com.damastah.deflash;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Compress {
    private static final int BUFFER = 2048;

    private ArrayList<File> _files;
    private String _zipFile;

    public Compress(ArrayList<File> files, String zipFile) {
        _files = files;
        _zipFile = zipFile;
    }

    public void zip() {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile);

            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));

            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            Log.e("Compress - zip", "test");
            for (int i = 0; i < _files.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files.get(i)
                        .getAbsolutePath());
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
                ZipEntry entry;
                if (_files.get(i).getAbsolutePath().contains("."))
                    entry = new ZipEntry(_files
                            .get(i)
                            .getAbsolutePath()
                            .substring(
                                    _files.get(i).getAbsolutePath()
                                            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                else
                    entry = new ZipEntry(_files.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
                out.putNextEntry(entry);

                int count;
                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not android developer so consider this code as a TIP only

```
class ZipCompress {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String dir = "d:\\My folder\\";
        // this entries I want to put in archives in the way they are now
        String[] entries = { "temp\\folder1\\file1.txt", "temp\\folder2\\file2.txt",
                "temp\\file3.txt" };

        ZipOutputStream zipos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(dir + "archive.zip")));

        // time to create entries and fill them with data
        for (String entrie : entries) {
            System.out.println("Writing file: " + dir + entrie);

            // prepering file stream
            BufferedInputStream fileStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(dir + entrie));

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//          Here we decide how we entry will look like in archive.
//          We use only part of path from String[] entries
//          like "temp\\folder1\\file1.txt"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entrie);

            newEntry.setComment("comment to entry: " + newEntry);

            // now lets put this entry in archive
            zipos.putNextEntry(newEntry);

            // lets put data from file to current archive entry
            int c;
            while ((c = fileStream.read()) != -1)
                zipos.write(c);
            fileStream.close();
        }
        zipos.close();
    }
}
```

### Edit

I am not sure what you want to do here

```
if (_files.get(i).getAbsolutePath().contains("."))
                    entry = new ZipEntry(_files
                            .get(i)
                            .getAbsolutePath()
                            .substring(
                                    _files.get(i).getAbsolutePath()
                                            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

From what i see it removes path to file leaving just file name (something like `_files.get(i).getName()`). If that is true then that is why you don't have folder structure in your zip file. You are saying that zip entry should be just that file name, without any folders.

So if you want zip file to contain some part of path from 
`/my/full/path/to/folder/temp/folder1/file1` like `temp/folder1/file1` just remove unnecessary part of that path when you create ZipEntry for example

```
String dir = "/my/full/path/to/folder/";
for (int i = 0; i < _files.size(); i++) {
...
    if (_files.get(i).getAbsolutePath().contains(".")) {
        entry = new ZipEntry(_files
            .get(i).getAbsolutePath().replace(dir, ""));
...
```

Comment: To specify file paths, you should use nested File constructors or [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator), not literal backslashes, to keep your code portable.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for tip. Every day I learn something new :)

Comment: More of a tip to anyone reading the answer than a correction really, using the literal makes the code sample easier to read without helper functions.

Comment: So there's no one or two line fix to the existing code, huh? I'm just looking at the answer here, and I don't see the line that handles the folders in the archive.

Comment: @Damastah check my edit and tell me if it works for you or not

Comment: @Damastah My wild guess is that the "folders" are created based what the `name` of the ZIPEntry is, and your original code just cuts off everything before the last slash of the file path.

Comment: @millimoose I have same opinion, that is why i wrote "something like `_files.get(i).getName()`"

Comment: @Pshemo I dont know why I put that code in there either. I'll start adding comments. I commented out that while first part of the if block there and it creates the structure as desired, with a small, hitch. the root folder of the zip contains a directory with no name. like " /folder/whatever" I checked my code, but couldnt find anything. This is what I get [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruy29zcra27a8c9/ScreenShot.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruy29zcra27a8c9/ScreenShot.png)

P.S: Thanks for that .replace() function. Didn't know I could do that with Strings. I'm learning so much from the question.

Comment: @Damastah I am not sure why you have this folder. Maybe entry cant start with `/` mark and zip think that there is some empty named folder fist (it is just a wild guess). So try to remove first `/` from your entry like `/folder/whatever` to `folder/whatever` and let me know if that helped

Comment: You're a genius! I wish I could give you a cookie or something... that was it. I had also noticed that before, when I opened it with winRar, the directory was structured like this 
D:\\dir\dir2. 
Now, there's no blank folder. Thank you, @Pshemo.

Comment: @Damastah I am glad I could help. Also it was probably not because entry cant have `/` at beginning, but because `/` is root directory in lot of OS, so my previous comment was real lucky shot :)